# problem with Zend Exception

Tags: php, zend-framework, exception

I using Zend Gdata library for search video Youtube API.
If I make a bad request, then a zend exception..
Example:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException' in D:\Webserver\domains\loc\controller\Zend\Gdata\App.php:710
Stack trace:
#0 D:\Webserver\domains\loc\controller\Zend\Gdata.php(221): Zend_Gdata_App->performHttpRequest('GET', 'http://gdata.yo...', Array, NULL, NULL, NULL)
#1 D:\Webserver\domains\loc\controller\Zend\Gdata\App.php(876): Zend_Gdata->performHttpRequest('GET', 'http://gdata.yo...', Array)
#2 D:\Webserver\domains\loc\controller\Zend\Gdata\App.php(764): Zend_Gdata_App->get('http://gdata.yo...', NULL)
#3 D:\Webserver\domains\loc\controller\Zend\Gdata\App.php(220): Zend_Gdata_App->importUrl('http://gdata.yo...', 'Zend_Gdata_YouT...', NULL)
#4 D:\Webserver\domains\loc\controller\Zend\Gdata.php(187): Zend_Gdata_App->getEntry('http://gdata.yo...', 'Zend_Gdata_YouT...')
#5 D:\Webserver\domains\loc\controller\Zend\Gdata\YouTube.php(293): Zend_Gdata->getEntry('http://gdata.yo...', 'Zend_Gdata_YouT...')
#6 D:\Webserver\domains\loc\controller\Yo in D:\Webserver\domains\loc\controller\Zend\Gdata\App.php on line 710
```

But I do not want users of my site have seen this error ... I need to catch this error and cause no Exception and just want to get the text of the error .. What should I do?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Put the code that causes the exception into a try/catch statement

```
try {
    // code calling Zend_Gdata_App->performHttpRequest
} catch(Zend_Gdata_App_HttpException $e) {
   $message = $e->getMessage();
   // do something with $message now
}
```

More information: http://de3.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php